# android native to javascript messaging best practice

Tags: javascript, android, api, webview, messaging

I need to make a decent android to javascript messaging and vice versa, since it will be used heavily in a very large project.
One way to do that is to define my `JSInterface` and pass a reference to `webview.addJavascriptInterface()` to send from JS to native and `webView.loadUrl("javascript: /*some javascript*/ ");` to send back from native code to JS.
My question is any there other ways to do that and if yes what would be the best practice?